# What is wrong with my answer?

Tags: graphing-functions

[image]

The question asks me to calculate area under the graph. Seeing as gradient =  -1, the x intercept is 60. The area under the graph would be 360, but this is wrong. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Are you sure the question doesn't ask for only the area **specifically shown** on the graph, which would be $(25-0)(12+7)/2=237.5$?

Answer (score 0):

Check the scales: each vertical line is $5$ units apart, and each horizontal line is only $1$ unit apart. This makes the gradient $-\frac{1}{5}$. Splitting into a triangle and rectangle, I make the area to be:
$$25 \times 1 + \frac{1}{2} \times 25 \times 5 = 87.5 \text{ units}^2.$$

Comment: This isn't the area under the graph, since the question is asking to calculate area under the graph down to the x  axis. Most of the area is not shown in  the diagram.

Comment: @oscar6721 Are you also assuming that the area is bounded by the $y$-axis?

Comment: Yes it is - the instructions state it

Comment: @oscar6721 Then, I also make the area $360 \text{ units}^2$. What makes you think this answer is incorrect?

Comment: It is an online worksheet, and as such the answers are checked automatically. I can't see any other possible answer, but the website says it is wrong.

Comment: @oscar6721 Did you try inputting $87.5$?

Answer (score 0):

You have different scales for $x$ and $y$. With equal units it seems as here:

[image]

As you can see, the gradient is not $-1$, but $-{1 \over 5}$.

Comment: I didn't phrase the question correctly - I know this  and this is why  I get 360 as  my  answer.

Answer (score 0):

The area under the graph *is* $360$, if you mean that it is bounded by $x$-axis.

But in your picture it is bounded by lines $y=6$, $x=0$, and $x=25$, so the area in **your** picture is $87.5$. Maybe your task was to determine *this* area.